Two Photons are Traveling
Two photons, photon A and photon B, are traveling in the same direction at the speed of light, $c$. How fast does photon B appear to be traveling from the perspective of photon A?

$A$ doesn't have a perspective, there are no coordinate frames moving at $c$.
Nevertheless, you can naively use the velocity addition fromual:
$$ v_{21} = \frac{v_1+v_2}{1+v_1v_2/c^2}=(c-c)/(1+(c)(-c)/c^2)=0/0$$
well I guess you can't. See 1st paragraph.

But then the photon would be at rest...

Just think: what should A do to measure the speed of B, and you see the question is meaningless.

@ChristinaDaniel It is not a logical contradiction - it is a domain error.  The equations are simply not valid.

Also consider how much time either photon experiences from the perspective of any observer. Photons are always observed to move at $c$ in any reference frame, which means that their Lorentz factor $\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\approx\infty$ is infinite. If you invert the differential on the left, you obtain $\frac{\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{1}{\gamma}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0$, so from any reference frame the photons experience no time. If they experience no time, they can't measure velocity (which is inherently time-based) to begin with.

@controlgroup don't talk about photon reference frame...there are none. It confuses noobs. But you can calculate $\gamma(c)=\infty$ to show it's a domain error. I actually excepted to get $0/1$ from the formula, but $0/0$ was even better.

@JEB Yes that's fair, it can be confusing. I'm talking about any arbitrary non-photon reference frame though, because photons are always seen to move at $c$. Your method is probably a bit clearer anyways.

@controlgroup agreed. So I watch YouTube physics ed videos for fun, and I've seen an uptick "photon's don't experience time" comments. (Not as bad when Veritasium dropped the one-way-speed-of-light video, which was great, but led to a wave keyboard "experts" (KBE). Nevertheless, the idea that $c$ particles can't decay/rotate pol/ is good to remember...but that then led to the wave of KBEs saying photons in media move at $c$, telling me I don't get it,  after 3B1B did a banger on the phase-shift view of index-of-refraction. I get it, but I am in the $v=c/n$ school for practical reasons.

I agree that it is good practice to call $c$ the speed of light in vacuum for that reason. It is true that photons don't experience time; they always move at $c$ in any reference frame, but due to internal reflection, refraction, etc. in a medium they can be effectively slowed down. Yes you are right and your answer gets +1
